# Solr query encoding cursorMark

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have cursorMark returned as cursorMark=AoE%2FBTAwZDI4ZWNjLTFmMGItNGIxMS1hZDI2LTQzMTVjZjljZGVmOA%3D%3D

However, when trying to get next set of results, on calling using (Solrj)...

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("cursorMark", cursorMark);
QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);

'%' in the value changes to %25 as below (see bold or between double stars):
cursorMark=AoE**%25**2FBTBkN2VjYjRlLTc5YmItNGZjYS05MDkzLTM4MWNiMTk5NTIyNQ**%25**3D**%25**3D
```

Due to this change solr is not able to get nextcursormark results. How to prevent it from encoding or changing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Method.POST instead of default GET solved this problem.